# How to populate the date of useSelector when using getStaticProps Next js

Tags: javascript, next.js

Im using NextJS/Redux Toolkit for e-commerce. I try to get the token in pre-render, the dispatch is working I can access the data in my page using props from `getStaticProp` but when using `useSelector` return no value why? But then I call the thunk in my `useEffect` in client, `useSelector` is working fine.

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const data = await appStore.dispatch(
    loginThunks.login.loginAsGuest({
      url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API,
     tenantId: 99,
    })
  );

  return {
    props: { data },
  };
};
```

Comment: Are you sharing the store between server and client ? how is it done ?